# SQL Report Server - how do I edit the report input?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, rdl

I'm fairly new to SQL Server Reporting Services.  I can edit the report output by editing the .rdl file in Visual Studio, however I'm trying to find out how to edit the input options available to report users - specifically the one shown below.  Where do I find this part of the report, and how do I find out how the data for the dropdown is being populated?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The 'input options' seem to be referred to as 'parameters' in SQL Server Reporting Services.  I found the following that explains clearly how to work with these:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3bzAs5FUt4